# Getting and displaying mongoose schema attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a mongodb collection filled with jokes, the schema looks like this

```
const mongoose = require ("mongoose");

// Dad Joke Schema
const jokeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    content: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Joke", jokeSchema)
```

What I want to do is display the content of the joke in the html. What I tried is this:

```
<div>
  <p><%= jokes.content %></p>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I do that, nothing displays but when I write <%= jokes %>, this displays the whole model, content together with the object ID.

My get method looks like this:

```
app.get("/dadJokeIpsum", (req, res) => {
    Joke.find({}, function(err, jokes) {
    if(err) throw err;
    res.render("dadJokeIpsum", {jokes:jokes})
    })
})
```

And I have required this at the top of my app.js:

```
Joke = require("./models/dadJoke"),
```

So, why is this happening? And how can I fix it?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jokes is an array.

So you need to display it like this:

```
 <% for (var i = 0; i < jokes.length ; i++) { %>
        <p> <%= jokes[i].content %> </p>
 <% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<p> <%=jokes[i].content  %> </p>
```

please use for loop using the length of jokes and fetch content.

and you can also use the **findOne** method for fetching some selected data.

```
Joke.findOne({}, function(err, jokes)
```